# Cordova build fails in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-10, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2017

Cordova build fails since upgrade to 2017. Error from output as below:

```
Building project: C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
Configuration : debug
Platform      : x64
C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(61,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\JavaScript\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WJProject.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
1>Done building project "PresalesApp.jsproj" -- FAILED.
```

Have had a look at modules installed and all Windows 10 UWP items seem to be installed.

Anyone else upgraded from 15-17 and had a similar issue?

Verbose Build Log:

```
1>  Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(Platform)' == 'android' AND '$(TelemetryEnabled)' == 'True' ) was evaluated as ( 'Windows-x86' == 'android' AND 'True' == 'True' ).
1>  Using "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>  Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata"
1>  Done executing task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata".
1>  Using "VsTac" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>  Task "VsTac"

    You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]No scripts found for hook "before_build".
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Checking config.xml for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in windows platform
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in windows platform. Continuing...
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "windows"
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Found "merges" for windows platform. Copying over existing "www" files.
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\StoreLogo.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-240.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\StoreLogo.scale-240.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-100.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\SplashScreen.scale-100.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-240.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Copying image from C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\res\screens\windows\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png to C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\images\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Updated project successfully
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]No scripts found for hook "pre_package".
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-ms-adal for hook "after_prepare": plugins\cordova-plugin-ms-adal\scripts\prePackage-windows.js
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Resolving module name for shelljs => shelljs
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Resolving module name for path => path
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Resolving module name for fs => fs
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
    ------ Building platform: windows
    ------ Build configuration options:  --debug -- --win --archs x86

    You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Reading build config file: C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\build.json
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Searching for available MSBuild versions...
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Found MSBuild v12.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Found MSBuild v14.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\
    [VSTAC_VERBOSE]Found MSBuild v4.0 at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
    Building project: C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : x86
    C:\code\presales\PresalesApp\PresalesApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(61,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\JavaScript\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WJProject.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
1>    MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  Done executing task "VsTac" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "PresalesApp.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "PresalesApp.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
```

In my BuildTools folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0) there isn't a Javascript Folder, only a TypeScript folder, but I have selected all options when installing the BuildTools?

Comment: You should be able to get more error info. Please change setting in Debug, click the Options..., open Projects and Solutions. In the Build and Run please set MSBuild project build output verbosity to Detailed and  MSBuild project build build log file verbosity to Detailed.

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT Thanks, have updated with more info

Answer (score 0):

After I removed the platform (VS 2015 generated directory) and rebuild, the CLI will get the correct build files for VS2017, and successfully build the project.

VS can do a better job by: Migrate document make it clear, or clear the build didn't clean up the corresponding platform directory.

Comment: This is driving me CRAZY!  I also upgraded to 2017 from 2015, and I'm getting the exact same error.  I've tried everything - uninstalling, reinstalling, rebooting.  Nothing works.  I'm just trying to build a Cordova project for the Windows platform...  I'm about to tell my customer that Cordova is not supported on Windows because you can't compile it...

Comment: @xinqiu: Can you elaborate the steps in detail that u followed to resolve this issue? I am facing this same issue

Comment: @Parth Doshi: There is a compiler generated directory called platform.  Just remove that directory and rebuild, see if it will benefit you.